# How to solve a system of nonlinear equations with inequality constraints and ensure convergence?

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence

Now I have the nonlinear equations with inequality constraints as below:
\begin{equation}  
\label{equ:kkt}
\begin{aligned} 
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
&\sum_{i=1}^M a_i \exp \left( -\frac{u_i}{\tau} \right) = \sum_{j=1}^N b_j \exp \left( -\frac{v_j}{\tau} \right)\\
& u_i + v_j + s_{ij} = C_{ij}\\
& s_{ij} \ge 0
\end{aligned} 
\right. 
\end{aligned} 
\end{equation}
I need to solve $u \in \mathbb{R}^{M \times 1}$, $v \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times 1}$ and $s \in \mathbb{R}^{M \times N}$.

Currently my solution:
(1) First set $s_{ij} = 0$ and fix $s_{ij}$ then optimize $u_i$, $v_j$. For optimize $v$ we set $u_i^{(l)} = C_{iw} - s^{(l)}_{iw}-v^{(l)}_w = \widehat{C}^{(l)}_{iw}-v^{(l)}_w$:
\begin{equation} \nonumber
\begin{aligned} 
\sum\limits_{j=1}^N  b_j  \exp \left( -\frac{v^{(l)}_j}{\tau} \right)   = \exp \left( \frac{ v^{(l)}_w }{\tau} \right) \sum\limits_{i=1}^M  a_i \exp \left( -\frac{   \widehat{C}^{(l)}_{iw} }{\tau} \right) \quad {\rm for} \quad \forall w \in \{ 1, 2, \cdots, N\}
\end{aligned} 
\end{equation}
Then we can solve the results for $v^{(l)}$.

Meanwhile we optimize $u$ and we set $v_j^{(l)} = C_{rj} - s^{(l)}_{rj}-u^{(l)}_r = \widehat{C}^{(l)}_{rj}-u^{(l)}_r$:
\begin{equation} \nonumber
{
\begin{aligned} 
\sum\limits_{i=1}^M  a_i \exp \left( -\frac{u^{(l)}_i}{\tau} \right)  = \exp \left( \frac{ u^{(l)}_r }{\tau} \right) \sum\limits_{j=1}^N  b_j \exp \left( -\frac{   \widehat{C}^{(l)}_{rj} }{\tau} \right) \quad {\rm for} \quad \forall r \in \{ 1, 2, \cdots, M\}
\end{aligned}
}
\end{equation}

Finally we update $s$ via $s^{(l+1)}_{ij} = \max(0, C_{ij} - u^{(l)}_i - v^{(l)}_j)$ for the next iteration.

I have tried this in my Python program, it works well. However, I still have questions below:

<1> Is my solving process mathematically reasonable?

<2> Continuing on, if the answer is yes, how can we prove the convergence of this algorithm?

<3> Continuing on, if the answer is no, how to correctly solve the above questions with convergence guarantee?

Many Thanks to all of you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sir, it's a slight overkill actually.

1. Select such $i_0$ and $j_0$ that $a_{i_0}$ and $b_{j_0}$ are of the same sign; if one can't select - до побачення, the problem is infeasible.
2. Denote $C = \min \limits_{i, j} C_{ij}$. Now set $v_i = \frac{C}{2} - x$ for all $i$ and $v_j = \frac{C}{2} - x$ for all $j$. Reset $v_{i_0} = \frac{C}{2} - y$, $v_{j_0} = \frac{C}{2} - z$. Now for all nonnegative $x, y, z$ all linear constraints are satisfied.
3. Now the first constraint is

$$ \sum \limits_{i \neq i_0} a_i e^{-\frac{C - 2x}{2\tau}} + a_{i_0} e^{-\frac{C - 2y}{2\tau}} = \sum \limits_{j \neq j_0} b_j e^{-\frac{C - 2x}{2\tau}} + b_{j_0} e^{-\frac{C - 2z}{2\tau}}$$
or
$$ \sum \limits_{i \neq i_0} a_i e^{\frac{x}{\tau}} + a_{i_0} e^{\frac{ y}{\tau}} = \sum \limits_{j \neq j_0} b_j e^{\frac{x}{\tau}} + b_{j_0} e^{\frac{z}{\tau}}.$$

Finding a feasible solution of the latter satisfying $x, y, z \geq 0$ is more-less obvious, and the solution always exists since $a_{i_0}$ and $b_{j_0}$ have the same sign.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Many Thanks for your apply! It really works!